# Manage the event on click on several files

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this html page that contains 5 div:

```
<body>
    <div id='elementToClick'></div>
    <div id='elem0'></div>
    <div id='elem1'></div>
    <div id='elem2'></div>
    <div id='elem3'></div>

    <script src='all.js' rel='script'></script>
    <script src='page1.js' rel='script'></script>
    <script src='page2.js' rel='script'></script>
    <script src='page3.js' rel='script'></script>
</body>
```

and 4 .js files.
The `all.js` file is "normal", it creates two squares (one black) and one red.
The other 3 .js files (`page1.js`, `page2.js`, `page3.js`) each create a square and use an IIFE approach.

What I would like is that when the user clicks on the black square, the other 4 squares change color (from a light to a dark shade).

[Here is the complete code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ShqFuIhAwXvARfYJeDqp?preview).

This code doesn't work because the color is changed only to the last square and not to the others. Why?

Comment: As Glubey mentinoned in their [answer](/a/50631936/4235784) you are overwriting event listeners. The solution to this is in my [answer](/a/50613088/4235784) to yesterday's [*"Get the event functions in d3.js"*](/q/50610722), i.e. use  namespaces to register multiple listeners for the same event type. However, your approach looks a bit clumsy and does not really seem to make sense as was mentioned by Gerardo Furtado in his [comment](/q/50524814#comment88063205_50524814) to your previous question. To make your life easier I suggest you should rethink your entire approach to this.

Comment: @altocumulus Thanks for the advice. Since I have several pieces of code that are common, I decided to put these parts in the `all.js` file. The other files contain code related to a particular graphic. It doesn't seem a bad approach to me, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the last eventListener (`elementToClick.on('click', function () { … });`) **overwrites** the other ones. To fix this, you have to put everything in *one* eventListener function.

---

*Your code* (mind my commends and the console!)*:*

```js
// all.js

var currentFill = 'normal';

var elem0 = d3.select('#elem0')
 .append('svg')
 .append('g')
 .append('rect')
 .attr('id', 'elem0rect')
 .attr('width', 50)
 .attr('height', 50)
 .attr('fill', 'red');

var elementToClick = d3.select('#elementToClick')
 .append('svg')
 .append('g')
 .append('rect')
 .attr('id', 'elemToClickId')
 .attr('width', 100)
 .attr('height', 100)
 .attr('fill', 'black');

elementToClick.on('click', function() {
    console.log('#elem0 changed');
    if(currentFill == 'dark') {
      //currentFill = 'normal';
      d3.select('#elem0rect').attr('fill', 'red');
    } else {
      //currentFill = 'dark';
      d3.select('#elem0rect').attr('fill', 'darkred');
    }
 });
  
// -> If you would click on #elementToClick now, the #elem0 would change its color.


// page1.js

(function page1() {

var elem1 = d3.select('#elem1')
 .append('svg')
 .append('g')
 .append('rect')
 .attr('id', 'elem1rect')
 .attr('width', 50)
 .attr('height', 50)
 .attr('fill', 'cyan');

elementToClick.on('click', function() {
    console.log('#elem1 changed');
    if(currentFill == 'dark') {
      d3.select('#elem1rect').attr('fill', 'cyan');
      currentFill = 'normal';
    } else {
      d3.select('#elem1rect').attr('fill', 'darkcyan');
      currentFill = 'dark';
    }
  });

})();
  
// -> If you would click on #elementToClick now, only #elem1 would change its color.

// page2.js
(function page2() {

var elem2 = d3.select('#elem2')
 .append('svg')
 .append('g')
 .append('rect')
 .attr('id', 'elem2rect')
 .attr('width', 50)
 .attr('height', 50)
 .attr('fill', 'violet');

elementToClick.on('click', function() {
    console.log('#elem2 changed');
    if(currentFill == 'dark') {
      d3.select('#elem2rect').attr('fill', 'violet');
      currentFill = 'normal';
    } else {
      d3.select('#elem2rect').attr('fill', 'darkviolet');
      currentFill = 'dark';
    }
 });

})();

// -> If you would click on #elementToClick now, only #elem2 would change its color.


// page3.js
(function page3() {

var elem2 = d3.select('#elem3') // 'var elem3' instead of 'var elem2'!!!
 .append('svg')
 .append('g')
 .append('rect')
 .attr('id', 'elem3rect')
 .attr('width', 50)
 .attr('height', 50)
 .attr('fill', 'GreenYellow');

elementToClick.on('click', function() {
    console.log('#elem3 changed');
    if(currentFill == 'dark') {
      d3.select('#elem3rect').attr('fill', 'GreenYellow');
      currentFill = 'normal';
    } else {
      d3.select('#elem3rect').attr('fill', 'lime');
      currentFill = 'dark';
    }
 });

})();

// -> If you click on #elementToClick, only #elem3 will change its color (see console).
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
 <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

 <div id='elementToClick'></div>
 <div id='elem0'></div>
 <div id='elem1'></div>
 <div id='elem2'></div>
 <div id='elem3'></div>
    
</body>
```